# Rails has_many and belongs_to returns nil

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord, associations

I have two models 'articles' and 'bookmarks' and have associated them using a specific column 'article_doi' as foreign_key.

In article.rb,

```
has_many :bookmarks, class_name: 'Bookmark', foreign_key: "article_doi", dependent: :destroy
```

In bookmark.rb,

```
 belongs_to :article, class_name: 'Article', foreign_key: "article_doi"
```

But when I do article_object.bookmarks, it returns a nil
Also when I do bookmark_object.article, it returns nil.

What has gone wrong?

Comment: you did not create association in db, most likely - meaning there is no associated objects yet

Comment: No there is. In bookmarks table, I have an bookmark object with article_doi column with value 'abc' which is the 'doi' of an article object

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As @AndreyDeineko said, there are a couple steps for getting a has_many/belongs_to association to work:

1. Add the `has_many/belongs_to` declarations to your models (*looks like you did this already*).
2. Create and run a [database migration](http://edgeguides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_migrations.html) to add the `article_doi` column to the `bookmarks` table in your database (the model that has `belongs_to` is the table which holds the reference).
3. Restart your rails server or console, so it notices the new columns.

Finally, you actually need to save some records in the db that are linked!

```
a = Article.first
b = a.bookmarks.build
b.save!
a.reload.bookmarks.count # => 1
```

Comment: article_doi column to both tables? I have 'doi' column in article table. and article_doi column in bookmarks table.

Comment: You're right - only the bookmarks table needs the `article_doi` column. Edited my answer!